# How to markup non-human-language text in HTML?

Tags: seo, html, markup, accessibility

Considering the needs of screen readers, browser spell-checking, search engines, etc. how should non-human-language text be marked up in HTML?

Should it be wrapped in a particular tag?
Is there a standard special `lang` attribute for the enclosing tag (eg. `""`)?

Note that we may wish to mark up a form input as accepting some sort of non-human-language text.

Examples of non-human-language text:

- a short cryptographic hash
- a large block of encrypted data
- proprietary formal notation
- ASCII art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the actual content (there is an important difference between, e.g., a hash and ASCII art) and the context (editable vs. presented content). So after choosing the appropriate element (and possibly WAI-ARIA), HTML5 offers the following options:

- The language tag `zxx` ([IETF BCP 47](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47#section-4.1)/[IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry)) can be used for "no linguistic content":

  ```html
  <span lang="zxx"><!-- … --></span>
  ```
- The `translate` attribute ([HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/dom.html#the-translate-attribute)) can be used to specify that the content should not be translated:

  ```html
  <span translate="no"><!-- … --></span>
  ```
- The `spellcheck` attribute ([HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/editing.html#attr-spellcheck)) can be used to specify that editable content should not be checked for spelling/grammar errors:

  ```html
  <textarea spellcheck="false"><!-- … --></textarea>
  ```

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the <code> tag for anything code-like, hash-ish (pun), or data blocks. I use the <pre> tag for displaying direct ascii output (such as screen grabs from mainframes or art).

Comment: Definitely agree about <code>, but still curious about how I'd mark up a form input that expected non-language (eg. a textbox for ascii art) to prevent a spell-checker from complaining. Maybe it's not possible?

Comment: @Ian Mackinnon - you could use a style sheet to force a monospace font to be used for a textbox and use a code converter to convert any " " into &nbsp; characters to force spaces to translate properly regardless of spacing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific recommendations for WCAG 2.0 or even in HTML5 (yet). You can probably wrap it with a `<code>` tag (like Joel Etherton suggested).

ASCII art is different though. WCAG recommends that you provide the user a text description and a way to skip it. [See H86](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H86).